# How to schedule a jaspersoft report in the last date of every month?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to schedule a report to be emailed at the last day of each month so that the user could see the complete monthly report?

Comment: the next question is how? There is no option to setup anything for last day of the month. You can specify a day of a month but how you can set last day of the month?

Comment: Hey @AlexK kindly remove your comment. Its not helping.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by two ways:

1. Use [JasperReports Server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-report-scheduler)

or

2. Add and configure [quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). Then you can create a job which generate reports and send mail to users via [JavaMail api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).

Note- Not tested.